# Dynamic Job Scheduling using Spring 3

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, scheduled-tasks

I have developed a web crawler which crawls with Start URL as seed parameter. I want to allow users to schedule this task in terms of a Job if possible.

Currently I am using `Spring 3.1.2` and `Hibernate`.  I need to give users a front end which receives cronJob Parameters and based on that I want to run the crawler. Is it possible to do it using spring.

I read a bit about `Quartz` but the articles on SO or other websites are not at all clear or they are not complete in order to fully understand how to implement a scheduler in spring.

I know basics that there are three components to it

1. SchedulerFacotry
2. Trigger
3. Job (Service to Run)

I hope someone could guide me in correct direction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quartz scheduler is just the right tool for the job. For some reason almost all tutorials focus on defining jobs at startup, in XML - while Quartz is fully capable of *(re-|un-)* scheduling jobs at runtime.

You can and should takr advantage of Spring to start the Quartz Scheduler, but then you can interact with it directly from your code. Here is a simple example [from the documentation](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/examples/Example3):

```
JobDetail job = newJob(SimpleJob.class)
    .withIdentity("job1", "group1")
    .build();

CronTrigger trigger = newTrigger()
    .withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
    .withSchedule(cronSchedule("0/20 * * * * ?"))
    .build();

scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

Here you define a *job* (piece of Java code to run), *trigger* (when to run it, user can supply any valid CRON expression) and wrap it all by scheduling it. The *scheduler* instance can be injected by Spring. Spring will also handle proper shutdown.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but is it possible to do it using `TimerFactoryBean` `ScheduledTask` provided by spring rather than using Quartz.. As in the documentation there is a mention about this method also. have you explored that?

Comment: `newJob(...)` is actually `JobBuilder.newJob(...)`. In the example above, the assumption is that the static method `newJob(...)` is imported statically thus no need to refer it by its class name.

Comment: The same applies for `TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()` and `CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(...)`

Comment: @dhruvenkumar-shah I didn't find any documentation about to do it dynamically, only when your application starts.